# Prepare the Drawer Navigation menu after the User login page depends on the User Type

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

We are creating the AppStack and Auth Stack for our application using createSwitchNavigator

our switch component looks like

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { 
     createSwitchNavigator,
     createStackNavigator,
     createAppContainer 
    } from 'react-navigation';
    
import LoginForm from './Forms/LoginForm';
import ShellForm from './Forms/ShellForm';

AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: LoginForm });
AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Shell: ShellForm});

const AppContainer =  createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        App: AppStack,
        Auth: AuthStack,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Auth',
      }
  ));


export default class RootAppContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return  <AppContainer />
   }
}
```

And in the shell we are creating the dynamic drawer menu. The initial app will load Auth Stack where we have login form and Forgot password.

Since we imported the ShellForm in the Header on js load it fires all the const variable and tries to fetch the menu.

our shell form looks like

```js
getAppContainer = () =>{
// get menus from we depends on the User logged in 
  var MenuBarInfo = require('../JsonData/Menu.json');
  getMenus({}, getMenuSuccess, getMenuFailure);

  var drawerlist = this.getDrawerListItems(MenuBarInfo.MenuItems)  
  var drawerOptions = {
    contentComponent: MenuComponent,
    initialRouteName:'Home',
    drawerBackgroundColor: 'white',
    drawerWidth: 300,
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: true,
    }

  }

drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    drawerlist ,
    drawerOptions
  );
  return createAppContainer(drawer);
}

   const DrawerNav = getAppContainer();
```

since the DrawerNav is a const variable it trying to prepare the menu is there any way to achieve this and avoid this loading upfront.

is there any way to start rendering the ShellForm only after the Login is done.

Comment: Did you find any solution, I am still looking for this

Comment: Yeah, Don't put the const variable outside, Create a component and make all the const methods inside that component and return the DrawerNav in the render method